# Alternative way to Paste Select * from in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, keyboard-shortcuts, user-defined

Is there any way to create a short cut for

```
select * from
```

I will be typing this 100+ times a day. Is there any user defined shortcut that we can create in Window to paste this text.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you typing this hundreds of times a day? This is an anti pattern in production code.

Comment: If you are using SQL server management studio then check this post-https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93388/how-do-i-add-keyboard-shortcuts-in-ssms-2012-to-run-a-specific-query